# When sharing file, why does SP send access request when the people sharing both already have access?

Tags: access, share, auto-approve

We have a SharePoint 2013 site that is open access company-wide (NT authenticated users have "contribute no delete" access). When a user clicks on a file and selects "Share" to send it to somebody else in the company, it sends me (as the site owner) an email and I have to approve or decline. I don't want to have to do this, as they both already have access. I know I can turn off access requests completely, but this stops them from having the option to share. How can I turn off access requests but still allow end-users to share files using the "Share" option?

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a tricky situation, so you may need to leverage a **custom permissions level** and workflow engine to pull this off.

Each time that a document is added to the library, you should kickoff a workflow to give users a custom permissions level for that item that gives them "Contribute/No Delete/Manage Permissions" access to that **item**.

The users may have permissions to access, and even edit the document, but you are receiving the Administrative approval requests because you are the site Admin, and they lack the '**Manage Permissions**' permissions level, so they technically cannot invite any users to use a document

> When a user who doesn't have the ability to manage permissions for a site shares the sites with another user, the request is first routed to the admin for approval.

([REFERENCE](http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=116)).